# ApplicationEventPublisher is not available as Bean in Filter using WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using ApplicationEventPublisher to publish events from Spring MVC components i.e. Service, Controller etc. Now I am trying to access ApplicationEventPublisher in my Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) implementation using WebApplicationContextUtils but it says no such bean of type ApplicationEventPublisher.

```
ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext()).getBean(ApplicationEventPublisher.class)

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No such bean of type org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher
```

Comment: The `ApplicationContext` is the `ApplicationEventPublisher`. SO in short just remove the `getBean(ApplicationEventPublisher.class) part.

Comment: @M. Deinum it fixed my issue. Thanks!